# Display current location after GPS is enabled in android

Tags: android, gps, skmaps

I am new in `Skobbler map`. I using the `Skobbler map` to display my current location. Initially the `marker` is at somewhere in the map.
[image]

I have set the default location at United States of America. So that, when i open the application it displays this. But, the marker is still somewhere in the map, above the sea. To display default location, I used this:

```
SKCoordinateRegion region = new SKCoordinateRegion();
region.setCenter(new SKCoordinate(-97.1867366, 38.4488163));
region.setZoomLevel(5);
mapView.changeMapVisibleRegion(region, true);
```

[image]

After that, when I enabled the `GPS`, the marker must move and shows my current location within time. What can be done to refresh the map to show my current location. What can be done to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR :

```
SKCoordinate coordinates = new SKCoordinate (-97.1867366, 38.4488163)
SKPosition lastSKPosition  = new SKPosition (coordinates);
SKPositionerManager.getInstance ().reportNewGPSPosition (lastSKPosition);
mapView.centerOnCurrentPosition (ZoomLevel, true, AnimationDuration);
mapView.setPositionAsCurrent (lastSKPosition.getCoordinate (), Accuracy, center);
```

Not being an expert on Skobbler, I don't like very much the Skobbler SDK as it looks too complex to me and the doc very poor, too much methods and classes, so I try to leverage the Android SDK and Google APIs as much as I can.

This is not a production ready code but just so you can get the picture.

This is how I like to organize my code when it comes to location :

**Abstract Location activity from which you'll extend all the activities that use location :**

```
public abstract class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GeoLocService locationService;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        if (GeoLocService.checkLocationPerms (this)) {
            initLocService ();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart () {
        super.onStart ();
        if (locationService != null) {
            locationService.onStart ();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult (int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult (requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == 1000) {
            if (GeoLocService.checkLocationPerms (this)) {
                initLocService ();
                locationService.onStart ();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume () {
        super.onResume ();
        if (locationService != null) {
            locationService.onResume ();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause () {
        super.onPause ();
        if (locationService != null) {
            locationService.onPause ();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop () {
        if (locationService != null) {
            locationService.disconnect ();
        }
        super.onStop ();
    }

    private void initLocService () {
        GeoLocService.LocationResponse response = new GeoLocService.LocationResponse () {

            @Override
            public void onLocation (Location location) {
                onLocationSuccess (location);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure (int errorCode) {
                onLocationFailure (errorCode);
            }
        };
        locationService = new GeoLocService (this, response);
    }

    protected void stopFetchingLocations () {
        if (locationService != null) {
            locationService.stopLocationUpdates ();
            locationService.disconnect ();
        }
    }

    protected GeoLocService getLocationService () {
        return locationService;
    }

    protected abstract void onLocationSuccess (Location location);
    protected abstract void onLocationFailure (int errorCode);
}
```

**GeoLoc Service that provides geoloc handling methods :**

```
public class GeoLocService implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    public final static long    UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;

    public final static long    FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    private GoogleApiClient     googleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest     locationRequest;
    private LocationResponse    locationResponse;
    private Location            currentLocation;

    private Date                lastUpdateTime;

    public GeoLocService (Activity context, LocationResponse locationResponse) {
        this.locationResponse   = locationResponse;

        googleApiClient         = new GoogleApiClient.Builder (context)
            .addConnectionCallbacks (this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener (this)
            .addApi (LocationServices.API)
            .build ();

        createLocationRequest ();
    }

    public void onStart () {
        if (googleApiClient != null) {
            googleApiClient.connect ();
        }
    }

    public void onResume () {
        if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected ()) {
            startLocationUpdates ();
        }
    }

    public void onPause () {
        if (googleApiClient != null && googleApiClient.isConnected ()) {
            stopLocationUpdates ();
        }
    }

    public void disconnect () {
        if (googleApiClient != null) {
            googleApiClient.disconnect ();
        }
    }

    protected void createLocationRequest () {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest ();
        locationRequest.setInterval (UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval (FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        locationRequest.setPriority (LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    public void startLocationUpdates () {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates (googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    public void stopLocationUpdates() { 
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(googleApiClient, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        if (currentLocation == null) {
            currentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation (googleApiClient);
            lastUpdateTime  = Calendar.getInstance ().getTime ();
            sendUpdates ();
        }

        startLocationUpdates ();
    }

    private void sendUpdates () {
        if (locationResponse != null && currentLocation != null) {
            locationResponse.onLocation (currentLocation);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged (Location location) {
        currentLocation = location;
        lastUpdateTime  = Calendar.getInstance ().getTime ();
        sendUpdates ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended (int cause) {
        googleApiClient.connect ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed (ConnectionResult result) {
        if (locationResponse != null) {
            locationResponse.onFailure (result.getErrorCode ());
        }
    }

    public static boolean checkLocationPerms (Activity context) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission (context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission (context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions (
                    context,
                    new String [] {
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
                    },
                    1000
            );
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient () {
        return googleApiClient;
    }

    public Date getLastUpdatedTime () {
        return lastUpdateTime;
    }

    public interface LocationResponse {
        void onLocation (Location location);
        void onFailure (int errorCode);
    }
}
```

**And finally your Skobbler Activity :**

```
public class SkobblerActivity extends LocationActivity implements SKMapSurfaceListener {

    private final static float  ZoomLevel           = 15;
    private final static int    AnimationDuration   = 750;
    private final static float  Accuracy            = 1;

    private int                 placedOnCurrentPosCount;

    private SKMapViewHolder     mapHolder;
    private SKMapSurfaceView    mapView;

    private SKPosition lastSKPosition  = new SKPosition (new SKCoordinate ());

    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        .....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLocationSuccess (Location location) {
        convertLocToSKLoc (location);
        SKPositionerManager.getInstance ().reportNewGPSPosition (lastSKPosition);
        if (mapView != null) {
            boolean center = false;
            if (placedOnCurrentPosCount < 2 && (location.getLatitude () != 0 || location.getLongitude () != 0)) {
                center = true;
                mapView.centerOnCurrentPosition (ZoomLevel, true, AnimationDuration);
            }

            mapView.setPositionAsCurrent (lastSKPosition.getCoordinate (), Accuracy, center);

            placedOnCurrentPosCount ++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onLocationFailure (int errorCode) {
    }

    private void convertLocToSKLoc (Location location) {
        lastSKPosition.getCoordinate ().setLatitude (location.getLatitude ());
        lastSKPosition.getCoordinate ().setLongitude (location.getLongitude ());
    }

    .......................
}
```

Any critics from the skobbler developers to improve this are welcome :)

Comment: Cannot resolve method `centerOnCurrentPosition` . There is exterme `Zoom In` while displaying location. I want location must be display like shown in figure  above.

Comment: What version of the Skobbler Sdk are you using?

Comment: This is the latest one. I have fixed that zoom in issue. But, the `Camera` movement is so fast. When i move some distance from the current location, the `Camera` get updated so fast. It returns back from that distance to current location within 5 or 6 seconds. How do i stop that ? Because, i have a button for that work. Due to the automatic update of that `Camera` , my button is like meaning less.

Comment: Change the code inside `if (mapView != null)` by `if (placedOnCurrentPosCount < 1 && (location.getLatitude () != 0 || location.getLongitude () != 0)) {
                center = true;
                mapView.centerOnCurrentPosition (ZoomLevel, true, AnimationDuration);
mapView.setPositionAsCurrent (lastSKPosition.getCoordinate (), Accuracy, center);
            }`

Comment: Is there any method `centerOnCurrentPosition` for this ? It shows Cannot Resolve Method .

Comment: Nor sure I understand. But since you want your button to be responsible for the centering... the above code will work. Otherwise open a new question.
Don' forget to mark my answer as resolved if it helped you.

Comment: Why this map moves every time to default location and then moves to my current ? If i already enable GPS, then it must shows my current location . What do i need to do ?

Answer (score 1):

Set the FollowPositions to True :

```
mapView.getMapSettings().setFollowPositions(true);
```

This will make it so that the map is re-centered with every position update.

Comment: Cannot resolve method setFollowPositions .... This method is either something like this : `mapView.getMapSettings().setCurrentPositionShown(true); `  !!! Your answer is not what i am looking . Please, post in the comment instead of like this. Your answer totally conflict my question.

Comment: @SatanPandeya : I think you're using an old version of the SDK.